# While executing job its getting failed in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

While executing jobs in jenkins its getting failed,and i already set environmental variables in linux environment and it shows an error like"compilation error".can anyone help me please.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umxrQ.png)

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Your job runs with a JRE not with a JDK. Check your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install jdk for compiling, when it done confirm it with:

```
javac -version
```

Comment: yes i have done installation,but it is showing same error.

Comment: ok, then probably you need to configure jdk of jenkins: https://www.studytonight.com/jenkins/configuring-jdk-in-jenkins